# search post's field in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, search

I have a blog with posts. I created a search field, where whent you start to write a title of post, on my blog you will have this post. rest of them have display block. My post consists of picture, title and short description.

HTML

```
.main_content
   .titlePictures
       .blog_img
          img
       .textContent
          .title
             h2 
               a Title
          .allTxt
```

So I prepared a function in pure JS, which handle with this search field. And it works, buuuuut.. I have only a title of this post, no picture and no description. And my function has lot of loops, what I think is not proper :( How can I change this

https://codepen.io/aniaska4/pen/gOOBjwy

```
   document.querySelector(".search input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    let input = document.querySelector(".search input");
    console.log(input);
    const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    const title = document.querySelectorAll(".blog .articles .title h2");
      for (let i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
      let a = title[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      let txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      const pic = document.querySelectorAll(".titlePictures img");
       for (let y = 0; y < pic.length; y++) {
        const txt = document.querySelectorAll(".allTxt");
         for (let x = 0; x < txt.length; x++) {
           if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
           title[i].style.display = "block";
           txt[x].style.display = "block";
           pic[y].style.display = "block";
           } else {
            title[i].style.display = "none";
            txt[x].style.display = "none";
            pic[y].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want the search to look for the title field only? But still show all the info of the blog post, is it?

Comment: Yes, searching by title, but showing picture, title and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str.search](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) method

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/alielkhateeb/pen/eYYbNEa) that solves your problem.

I have added all the comments you need to understand the code, please let me know if you need any clarification.

```
document.querySelector(".search input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  let input = document.querySelector(".search input");
  const filter = input.value.toLowerCase();

  // Select all posts
  const posts = document.querySelectorAll(".main_content");

  // Loop on all the posts
  for(post of posts) {
    // Select the title of the post
    let title = post.querySelector('.title h2 a');

    // Search title text by filter
    let found = title.innerText.toLowerCase().search(filter);

    // If found === -1 hide the post, otherwise show it
    post.style.display = found === -1 ? "none" : "block";
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow! It is working. I did so many loops.. which was not necessary. Thank you for that. I found what I did wrong.